# Included file from a parent folder that includes a file from another folder

Tags: php, include, directory

The title is hard to understand, but my question is easy:

I have:

**config.php**

```
include('config_mysql.php');
include('language/english.php');
```

then I have: **index.php**

```
include('config.php');
```

and then: **/ajax/ajax_vote.php**

```
include('../config.php');
```

Why `index.php` includes both `config_mysql.php` and `language/english.php` but `ajax/ajax_vote.php` only includes the `config_mysql.php`?

Answer (score 0):

The base folder for `include()` is allways the base folder of the original script, so the `include()`s inside an `include()`d script will be non-intuitive:

`ajax/ajax_vote.php` will (try to) include

```
ajax/../config.php
  -> ajax/sonfig_mysql.php
     ajax/language/english.php
```

You might want to look at

```
$BASEDIR=dirname(__FILE__);
include("$BASEDIR/config_mysql.php");
include("$BASEDIR/language/english.php");
```

and friends.

Comment: No, in my case it actually includes the config_mysql.php (I promise!) on the base folder, the only problem is with the english.php file which is inside the language folder

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, the `language/english.php` is not in the same directory as `config.php`. Also, the `/ajax/ajax_vote.php` is somewhere outside from the root folder.

But still, PHP manages to include files correctly. I don't understand why the `/ajax/ajax_vote.php` is not including the file `language/english.php`. Correct me if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Totally, right, that's what is happening. `ajax_vote.php` doesn't include the file `language/english.php` but does include `config_mysql.php` strage... anyone else please?

Answer (score 0):

What Eugen said is true, this is because of the base path not being the same as your included script.

Also it seems from my tests (because I encountered a similar problem) that php include() will store another temporary include_path when including files, this is why ajax_vote.php could include config_mysql.php. To convince yourself, try to move config_mysql.php to your ajax folder: it will work the same, and config.php will be able to include it (but only when executing ajax_vote.php, NOT index.php!). In this case, you have two include paths: '/ajax/' and '/'.

However, when you use a path (not merely a filename to include, but also specify a folder in your string), the include path is only based on the executing script (eg: only '/ajax/').

You can fix this behaviour by doing:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/language/english.php'); // don't forget the prepended '/'
```

Or just:

```
include('/language/english.php'); // here again the prepended '/'
```

However I warn you that I don't fully understand yet why the second method works, you may be safer by using the first one with dirname().

/EDIT: I just found out that include('/path/to/file') is probably a bug on Windows OSes: on Windows it's equal to dirname(__ FILE__ ), but on UNIX it's equal to root path. So dirname(__ FILE__ ) is definately more reliable.